# Why does my program not return my required value?

Tags: python

```
def f(v1, v2, v3):
    if v1 == v2 and v2 == v3:
        print("Applying f to all three values gives the same result" + str(v1))

    if v1 == v2 and v1 != v3:
        print("Only applying f to x and y gives the same result")
        return v1
    if v2 == v3 and v2 != v1:
        print("Only applying f to y and z gives the same result")
        return v2
    if v1 == v3 and v1 != v2:
        print("Only applying f to x and z gives the same result")
        return v1
    if v1 != v2 and v2 != v3:
        print("Applying f to x,y,z gives all different results")


def check_equal(f, x, y, z):
    f(x, y, z)


tests = [(42, 1, 42), (1, 1, -5), (5, 4, -1), (5, 5, 5), (0, 0, 1), (-9, 9, 9), (9, 8, 90)]
for x, y, z in tests:
    print(check_equal(f, x, y, z))
```

This code checks which values: x,y and z are similar and prints to the user which are similair, wether they're all the same or all different and returns the a value if the integers do match.

The checks work however i cannot seem to return a value, just prints "none" to the console

Comment: Please update the indentation of your code. Python is very sensitive to indentation, as are python programmers.

Comment: Well, you are only returning a value in the 2,3, and 4 if statements, so if it's not that the function returns None (the default)

Answer (score 2):

The `check_equal` function does not return anything... Change it to

```py
def check_equal(f, x, y, z):
    return f(x, y, z)
```

Comment: Keep in mind that in some cases the `f` function also does not return anything, meaning that the `check_equal` function will still return `None` in those cases

Comment: That is true, but in the question he writes: _returns the a value if the integers do match_ so it is probably ok to return `None` some times